# How do I adjust my function to display the correct value using the code that I am using. Is it possible this way? Thanks

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How should I adjust this fun? When running the app the toast doesn't display the value, but as is. Hope that makes sense.   For ex: "Option:  @string/about_us"  would be displayed instead of that actual value
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

```
        var selectedOption = ""

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.about_us -> selectedOption = "@string/about_us"
            R.id.help -> selectedOption = "@string/help"
            R.id.item_1 -> selectedOption = "@string/item_1"
            R.id.item_2 -> selectedOption = "@string/item_2"
            R.id.item_3 -> selectedOption = "@string/item_3"
        }

        val text = "Option:  $selectedOption"
        val toastiest = Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        Toast.makeText(this, text, toastiest).show()

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Context#getString(stringResId)` to fetch the appropriate string from the ones you've defined (this also handles fetching the appropriate language version if you're using translations). You can't use the `@string/item_1` syntax here, that's an XML thing - you need to use `R.string.item_1`

You already have a `Context` (you're using it when you make the toast) so here's what I'd recommend:

```
val selectedOption = when (item.itemId) {
    R.id.about_us -> R.string.about_us
    R.id.help -> R.string.help
    R.id.item_1 -> R.string.item_1
    R.id.item_2 -> R.string.item_2
    R.id.item_3 -> R.string.item_3
    else -> null
}?.let { getString(it) } ?: "fallback message goes here"
```

So you map various IDs to their string resource ID, and you run `getString()` with the result, so you only need to write that once instead of repeating it for every line.

By passing `null` when nothing matches, and null-checking before the `let`, you can set a fallback string - either an ID matches and gets turned into a string, or you get that string after the `?:` elvis operator. Either way, `selectedOption` gets set to something, so you can make it a `val` because it's being defined right then and there

Comment: It worked like a charm! It took a minute to understand the last bit of code - ?.let { getString(it) } ?: "fallback message goes here" but I am understand a bit more now.  I tried running the app without the ?: "fallback message goes here" and it worked... do you see me ever needing to use that last bit? If the else is setting the text to null. Unless you're clicking an item from the menu, the toast wouldn't show up

Comment: I've seen you posting a bit as a learner so I thought I'd throw in something useful ;) Basically that ``when`` block returns an ``Int?``, as in a nullable ``Int``, because all the cases either evaluate to an ``Int`` or `null` (the ``else`` branch, basically). You need the else here because it needs to always evaluate to *something* when you're assigning a value (your version was a "do something, or don't" type of thing). By having the `?:` fallback, it guarantees both an `Int` result and a `null` result end up as a non-null `String`, so that's the `val`'s type. Up to you if it matters here!

Comment: But from what you're saying, nah it doesn't seem to matter. If you let it default to null, so `selectedOption` is a nullable `String?`, that'll still work fine when you throw it in the template string when you create `text`. If at some point the app is changed and another item is added (or whatever) but not handled in this `when` block, `text` will end up with "null" in its message - since it should never happen, it doesn't need to be a meaningful message for the user, y'know? One thing a default message does though, is it lets you make that null's meaning clear for someone reading the code

Comment: Always! I appreciate the wisdom. I need all the help I can get; thank you.

Comment: I haven't came across too many similar situations, so I don't typically use ?: nor the Elvis operator. Hopefully I build more apps that benefit from this and gain a deeper understanding of the topic. I appreciate your help for sure

Comment: do you know how to change the background color for the menu? The default is white. I have tried using <item name="itemBackground">@color/testcolor</item> in my themes file. I am using Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar as the parent

Comment: @Dareus basically as you use Kotlin more, you'll realise you don't want to have things being nullable (or ``var``s, but that's less of an issue) if you can help it, because the null-safety stuff (which is great and your friend) will expect you to handle the null cases. The ``?:`` (which is the Elvis operator, looks like eyes with a quiff!) is like an "if null then" fallback. And uh I can't really answer other questions in comments, but try setting `colorBackgroundFloating` in your theme. Menus and stuff are supposed to be lighter (raised closer to the "light") but they can be too light ime